# Ruby script cannot load a gem installed via bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am trying to include the ruby-mysql gem in my ruby script. I have installed the gem using bundler but when I run `bundle exec ./mysql_connector`, I receive the error ``` ./mysql_connector:4:in ``require': cannot load such file -- ruby-mysql (LoadError) ```. Can you please help me troubleshoot what the problem is?

**What I did**

**Installed rails in my home directory.**
I do not have root access to the server so I have installed rails in my local directory by following the instructions here:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-ruby-on-linux-as-a-user-other-than-root/

**Created a directory for my application.**
My application resides in my home directory in a folder called `connector`. It has a Gemfile that looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'ruby-mysql'
```

**Call `bundle install`.**

```
Using ruby-mysql 2.9.14
Using bundler 1.11.2
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
```

**Add dependencies to my script.** My script is in connector/mysql_connector and it reads:

```
#!/home/dcox/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'ruby-mysql'
```

**Make script executable.** I saw that you need to run `bundle exec` using an executable file, so I followed the instructions here to make my script executable: http://commandercoriander.net/blog/2013/02/16/making-a-ruby-script-executable/

**Run the script.** I execute using `bundle exec mysql_connector` and see:

```
/home/dcox/bin/mysql_connector:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- ruby-mysql (LoadError)
    from /home/dcox/bin/mysql_connector:4:in `<main>'
```

**Is it the $LOAD_PATH?** After searching around for answers, I discovered a lot of SO answers as well as a blog post (https://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/require-and-load-in-ruby-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file/) that seem to suggest the problem is that the gem is not installed in a directory on the $LOAD_PATH. Here is what I see when I run `$LOAD_PATH` from IRB:

```
irb(main):002:0> $LOAD_PATH
=> ["/home/dcox/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0", 
"/home/dcox/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux", 
"/home/dcox/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/home/dcox/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0", 
"/home/dcox/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux", 
"/home/dcox/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/home/dcox/lib/ruby/2.1.0", 
"/home/dcox/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux"]
```

Next I checked to see the location of ruby-mysql:

```
dcox@analytics1:~/connector$ bundle show ruby-mysql
/data/home/dcox/connector/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/ruby-mysql-2.9.14
```

Obviously my `connector/vendor/bundle` path is not on the $LOAD_PATH. I could add it, but I have a feeling I am missing something simple here because bundler is supposed to work as long as you follow the instructions, right?

Any advice or help is very much appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Have you looked at the instructions in `ruby-mysql`'s github? https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to require this specific gem, `require 'mysql'` should work (e.g., https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql/blob/master/test/test_mysql.rb#L10).

Comment: This worked! But does this mean I am bypassing Bundler?

Comment: My colleague explained to me that since the script is named `mysql.rb`, this is what I have to `require` in my ruby script!

Comment: Pasting from the [bundle exec docs](http://bundler.io/v1.1/bundle_exec.html) here, since it gets right to the point as to what using `bundle exec` buys you... 
`Exec runs a command, providing it access to the gems in the bundle.  While using bundle exec you can require and call the bundled gems as if they were installed into the systemwide RubyGems repository.`

So you're not bypassing Bundler by using `require`.  If you don't use `bundle exec` to run your script, unless the `ruby-mysql` is in your systemwide set, your script would not be able to require it.

Answer (score 0):

Your file should call `Bundler.setup` http://bundler.io/bundler_setup.html

Better yet, if you instead call `Bundler.require(:default)` it will setup and require all the gems in your Gemfile for you.

Comment: OK, I wanted to try this even though the answer above worked, because I am still not sure exactly what is happening and I'm interested to learn more.

I have the line `require 'bundler/setup'`, is that different from having the line `Bundler.setup`?

I also tried to execute the file using both of your two suggestions above but I received the same error. :\